# Mapping to contract

Tags: solidity, contract-design, storage, mapping

Solidity documentation [says](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#mappings) it is possible to use anything as mapping value, which I assume includes a contract:

> `_ValueType` can actually be any type, including mappings.

but I couldn't find an example or documentation on how to work with it.

If I have the following mapping, how can I know if the contract in the mapping exists, or have suicided?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract MyContract {
  // ...
}

contract MappingExample {
    mapping(uint32 => MyContract) inner_contracts;

    function do_something(uint32 key) {
        MyContract c;
        if(/* inner_contracts[key] exists??? */) {
            c = inner_contracts[key];
        } else {
            c = new MyContract;
            inner_contracts[key] = c;
        }

        // do stuff with c
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe Solidity's contracts are not really types, in that they are special compared to other types. You should use `mapping(uint32 => address)` instead, and refer to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8484/18295) answer for checking whether the contract on a particular address exists.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;


contract InnerContract {
    uint public value;
    function setValue(uint new_value) {
        value = new_value;
    }
}

contract Contract {
    mapping(address => InnerContract) public contracts;

    function makeNew() {
        contracts[msg.sender] = new InnerContract();
    }
    function initialize() {
      contracts[msg.sender].setValue(3);
    }
    function get() constant returns (uint) {
      return contracts[msg.sender].value();
    }
}
```

If you play with this code, you'll notice that calling initialize before makeNew doesn't work. The reason is that mapping has default value filled with zeros. In case of contract it's not a good idea.

> how can I know if the contract in the mapping exists, or have suicided?

Let's use another mapping for flags!

```
mapping(address => InnerContract) public is_contract_initialized;
```

If value is false(which is by default) then you should initialize your contract.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it works it will probably be very expensive. A couple of suggestions.

1. Store the deployed contract addresses (small), then instantiate the contracts as you need them: `MyContract c = MyContract(theAddress);`
2. Avoid `suicide/selfdestruct`. It just creates sinks and invalid OPCODES. Instead, if you want to ensure a contract is retired, flip a bit and use a modifier like `onlyIfRunning`. You can make that variable public and then easily inspect it: `if(c.isRunning()) {}`
3. You can potentially prune the list of deployed contracts but it's a rather more complex structure and it might be enough to just keep an append-only list as you go and use that `isRunning()` idea to ascertain which contracts are "shut down" and rejecting state-changes.

I made an example over here: [Is There a Simple Contract Factory Pattern?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13415/is-there-a-simple-contract-factory-pattern)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you sure `mapping(uint32 => MyContract)` isn't just a syntactic sugar for `mapping(uint32 => address)`? I thought `MyContract(theAddress)` was just a cast...

Comment: `MyContract` isn't an address. Variables cast as `MyContract` will have all the methods in the contract, whereas an `address` only has the methods that go with addresses. The sugar that might confuse the issue is that contract types are directly convertible to addresses. You can get away with `returns(address theContract) { return c; }`. I guess by "directly" they mean we don't have to explicitly recast them with something like `return address(c);`

Comment: @RobHitchens,Storing it as MyContract enables us to call methods of that contract directly, but I couldn't validate the "being very expensive" statement. Why would it be? What extra information other than contract address would this "Contract type" include? Solidity at compile time verifies that methods you are calling are present. I was curious, so I tried it https://ethfiddle.com/yug3vEjOBk and whether you call addDbAsAddress or addDbAsInstance, it consumes about same amount of gas. The IdDatabase contract is long to verify that DbController doesn't stores contrat's function names/signatures

Comment: You're bringing the whole bytecode of `MyContract` into `MappingExample`. The code for MyContract isn't shown, but let's say it's near the gasLimit because it's a complex beast. `MappingExample` will be that big plus additional bytecode for its own function. Multiple layers of this style lead to contracts that are too large to be deployed. This is what happens when you say `MyContract c`. You could just as well say `MyContractInterface c` and it would be smaller. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5726/what-is-the-purpose-of-interface-contracts